# Application get crash on textbox TextChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms

Mates, I am stuck in some problem, I'm using Entity Framework, and on textchange event I have to filter records and have to assign using autocompleteSource but I don't know why the application get crashed, I have searched but still didn't find fruitful result. Please help. Here is the code:

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection ChartCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();                    
txtChartNo.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear();

if (txtChartNo.Text.Trim() != string.Empty &&
    Convert.ToString(txtChartNo.Text.Trim()).Length > 0)
{
    List<Patient> pat =
        PatientManager
        .GetByChartNoForAutoComplete(Convert.ToString(txtChartNo.Text))
        .ToList();// fetching data from db using EF

    if (pat.Count > 0)
    {
        pat.ForEach(f =>
        {
            ChartCollection.Add(f.ChartNo + " - " + f.FullName);
        });
        txtChartNo.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ChartCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the complete exception message

Comment: i cant get any exception, i have tried alot.

Comment: There is a couple of places where you can get `NullReferenceException` but without the exception message it's just a wild guess.

Comment: What if pat is null? What do you mean by 'crash'? Consider Try/Catch block.

Comment: actully application get crash that's why i m unable to catch exception, i have tried two methods 1) show exception using Messagebox and 2) tried to write logfile, but failed in both methods

Comment: Try using Debug on an earlier point than the 'crash' point and move step by step from there.

Comment: @IdreesWassan Can you show the code which you used to catch the exception and show/log its details? Is there anything in the Windows Event Log when the application crashes?

Comment: and other thing i would like to tell you is i m running this application on remove PC and sqlServer is hosted at an other PC, when i run this application locally then don't get this issue. but this only occur at Remote PC. thanx

Comment: #Emmad Kareem i have spent more that two days. and i have provided more information in my previous comment. thanx

Comment: To see the exception while it is thrown, in Visual Studio go to Debug -> Exceptions... (or Ctrl+D, E) and check both checkboxes next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". It will stop your app the moment the exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no exception message I can point out two potential problems you may have run into in this code.

First, the `pat` collection may be `null`. If that's the case any operation on that will result in `NullReferenceException`. Guarding against `null` will be sufficient remedy.

```
if (pat != null && pat.Count > 0)
{
    // any operation on pat collection.
}
```

Second possibility is that you may have your data context disposed before you access the collection. I'm guessing inside the `GetByChartNoForAutoComplete` method you invoke the data context inside the `using` block. If INSIDE the block you DO NOT invoke `ToList()` as well then you actually do not fetch the data. Your code is attempting to retrieve the data when  `ToList` is invoked in your snippet but at that time the data context is already disposed.

Both suggestions are bit of a long shot but with very limited information you provided it's difficult to give anything more precise.

As a side note there are quite a few places where your code can be improved. `TextBox.Text` does not need to be converted to string. Also, to check if the string is empty use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.